# could not pass a char array properly

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, char

One function tries to pass char array to another, but without success:

```
char * ret() {
    char buf[32];
    buf[0]='1'; // buf char array contains 1
    buf[31]='\0';
    printf(buf);
    return buf;
}

int multiline() {
    char temp[32];
    strcpy(temp,ret()); // temp array doesn't contain 1 after this line
    temp[31]='\0'; 
    printf(temp);
}
```

Please tell me, how to fix this issue?

Comment: You're returning a local variable

Comment: Why do you expect it to have 1?  It's a bit unclear as to what you think is wrong with this code.  Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I would like to copy buf array (which was returned by a ret() function)
to the temp array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue by not returning a local variable (allocate a string or return a pointer to a statically allocated one):

```
char * ret() {
    char * buf = malloc(32*sizeof(char));
    buf[0]='1'; // buf char array contains 1
    buf[31]='\0';
    printf(buf);
    return buf;
}

int multiline() {
    char temp[32];
    char * returnedString = ret();
    strcpy(temp,returnedString);
    free(returnedString);
    temp[31]='\0'; 
    printf(temp);
}
```

Comment: The correct line is:
`char * buf = (char *)malloc(32*sizeof(char));`
but your answer really helped me! Thank you!

Comment: No, in C you do not usually cast the return value of malloc(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: With a line I mentioned earlier it compiles for me

Answer (score 2):

you are returning a pointer to a local variable `char buf[32];`. This array is allocated on the stack and only valid within the function but not outside of the function. 
You get undefined behavior when you access this array.

To return an array like this you should allocate it on the heap, eg. with `malloc()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a pointer to a local variable; as soon as the function returns, the local variable, along with the rest of the function's stack frame, is destroyed.

Instead, you can return a *copy* of the array; you could make one using `strdup()`.

As an aside, you're setting the first character of your array, and putting a \0 at the end, but the 30 characters in between just hold garbage. Normally the \0 at the end of a string is immediately after the valid characters, not all the way at the end of the array.