# C local variable address return warning

Tags: c, warnings, local-variables

I have this function in C:

```
static Node* newNode(void* e){
Node n={e,NULL,NULL};
return &n;
}
```

And while compiling I get the following warning that I would like to understand why it happens:

```
warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

What kind of dangers are lurking behind this?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables are destroyed when you return from a function. Accessing them after the function returned is undefined behavior, don't do this.

Comment: The code is just totally broken. It returns a pointer to the location the Node was in, but the Node is no longer there. So the returned pointer is garbage.

Comment: So I should make a copy of the value insted of passing its reference?

Comment: @Reonarudo use `malloc` in your `newNode` function to create the node: `Node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);`

Comment: @ouah Like this then: 
static Node* newNode(void* e){
 Node* n=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(*n));
 n->e=e;
 return n;
}

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because the scope of the variable is local to the function - once the function is returned, that variable is no longer in scope, and it's value is undefined.