# Local variable address used as errno

Tags: c, memory, malloc, local-variables

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct a
{
    void *ptr;
    unsigned long val;
};

void main()
{
    unsigned char errno;

    struct a *id;
    id = malloc(sizeof(*id));
    func2(id);
    printf("After changing %d\n", id->val);
}


void func2(struct a *id)
{
    unsigned char errno;
    func(id,&errno);
}

void func(struct a *id,void *ptr)
{   
    memset(id, 0, sizeof(*id));

    id->ptr = ptr;
    if (sizeof(id->val) >= sizeof(id->ptr))
    {   
        id->val = (unsigned long)id->ptr;
        return;
    }

}
```

when i am printing  id->val in main function it is printing -1075050593
. But i am trying to access a invalid address. Please explain. I am very new to c programming.

Comment: Also, you should turn on compiler warning messages.  You will find that this code doesn't compile cleanly.  You should fix all compilation problems first, and then ask the question if it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)

Comment: `func2(&id);` has an ampersand too many. And main() should return int. sigh.

Comment: Beware that `errno` has a fixed meaning in the context of C.

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `errno` in `func2()`. It probably gets initialised to 0 and then 0 gets assigned to `id->val` in `func()`.

Comment: @JensGustedt can you please explain ?

Comment: @shunty have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement **is not attempting to access an invalid address, it is just printing the address**:

```
printf("After changing %d\n", id->val);
```

what value it will hold is unknown as `id` is being incorrectly passed to `func2()`.

Some problems with the code (some already mentioned in the comments):

- incorrectly taking address of `id` when passing to `func2()` as `id` is already a `struct a*`
- implicit declarations of `memset()` and `malloc()` as missing include directives
- implicit declarations of `func()` and `func2()`
- return type of `main()` should be `int`

Comment: i made an edit instead of address of structure only pointer should be passed. printf("After changing %d\n", id->val); it trying to print a address which is invalid.

Comment: @shunty, it is just _printing_ the address value and is not attempting to access it which is fine. See http://ideone.com/ZH3Ws

Answer (score 1):

Usually, what is "accessing an invalid address"? It consists of 2 parts.
1, accessing: it includes read/write/execute.
2, invalid address: the kernel space and the un-malloced heap are the invalid address for the user application.

In this case, the address (&errno) belongs to the stack, so it is not an invalid address. And you doesn't read/write/execute the content in this address. So you are not accessing the invalid address.

BTW, with the "%d" placeholder in the printf() call, the "id->val" will be explained as a signed int type, it is why you got a negative value. Please use "%p" for pointers and "%u" for unsigned int.

Comment: so if i tries to access *id->val what will be the behavior?