# Not getting right Output of Character Array

Tags: c++, arrays, char-pointer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Pointer to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* func();

int main() {
    char* str;
    str = func();
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}

char*  func() {
    char * str;
    char p[] = "priyanka is a good girl";
    str = p;
    cout<<str<<"\n";
    return str;
}
```

gives the output,

> priyanka is a good girl
>
> priy

I did not understand what just happened here, why an incomplete array was given as output. I am a little new with this. Please help.

Comment: `rpiyanka is a good girl` no she is not. She does not indent her code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `func2()` `char p[]` is a local variable initialized on stack. Returning a pointer to stack variable is a bad idea(and is undefined behaviour as well), and I think your string "priyanka is a good girl" got overwritten when the function returned.

Answer (score 4):

Your function `func()` returns a pointer to a local variable, which later causes undefined behaviour when you try to access it.

Comment: oh yes, sending a pointer to local variable doesn't make any sense :P. thanks

Comment: I'd add that it's allocated on the stack. When the function returns, its stack frame (where the pointer points to) is deallocated, which is why you can get a partially correct/jumbled output, when some but not all of the old stack frame has been reused by something else.