# Arduino - Proper way to get response and parse a json array

Tags: c, arrays, json, arduino, arduino-uno

**Here is what I'm trying to do**: I have a django app with a REST api on it. One of the routers returns a json array that looks like this : `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and will always be the same size and containing integers.

Now, I have an Arduino Uno with an Adafruit cc3000 wifi shield on it. I manage to connect to the wifi, do my get request and print the result, even save it in a char *.

## My first problem is:

I'm pretty sure I'm not constructing my char array the right way (at least, not the proper way, I don't have a lot of experience with C, C++ etc.) if that's an excuse). And I think this prevents me to parse the json array.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

int PIN = 6;
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
StaticJsonBuffer<600> jsonBuffer;

#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3  
// These can be any two pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10

Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT,
SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER);
#define WLAN_SSID       "mywifi"
#define WLAN_PASS       "mypwd"
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2
uint32_t ip = cc3000.IP2U32(00,00,00,00);


void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!cc3000.begin())
  {
    while(1);
  }
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  char *ssid = WLAN_SSID;
  Serial.print(F("\nAttempting to connect to "));
  Serial.println(ssid);
  cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY);
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi network!");

  Serial.println(F("Request DHCP"));
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(3000);
  }
}


void loop(void){
  int lap = 0;
  if(!cc3000.checkConnected()){
    while(1){
    }
  }
  char *result;
  result  = send_request();
  result[71] = ']';
  JsonArray& root = jsonBuffer.parseArray(result);
  if (!root.success())
  {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
  }
  while(lap<61){
    for (int i=0; i<24; i++){
      long is_free = root[i];
      if (is_free == 0){
        strip.setPixelColor(i, 255, 0, 0);
      }
      if(is_free == 1){
        strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 255, 0);
      }
      if(lap % 2 ==0){
        if(is_free == 2){
          strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 255, 0);
        }
        if(is_free == 3){
          strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 255, 0);
        }
      }
      else{
        if(is_free == 2){
          strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        if(is_free == 3){
          strip.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
        }
      }
    }
    strip.setBrightness(15);
    strip.show();
    lap += 1;
    delay(1000);
  }  
}


char* send_request (void)
{
  char result[100];
  Serial.print(F("Initializing SendGET request\n"));
  Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 8000);

  if (client.connected()) {
    //starts client connection, checks for connection
    Serial.println(F("Adding state to DB\n"));
    client.println("GET /myurl/?format=json"); //download text
    client.println(F("Host: xx.xx.xx.xx"));
    client.println("Connection: close");  //close 1.1 persistent connection  
    client.println(); //end of get request
    Serial.println(F("Ending connection to DB\n"));
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection to server failed"); //error message if no client connect
    Serial.println();
  }
  int i = 0;
  while (client.connected()){
    while (client.available()) {
      if (i<71){
        //Read answer
        char c = client.read();
        result[i] = c ;
        i++;
      }
      else{
        client.close();
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To me `send_request()` is really dirty since I decided that `i` needed to be smaller than 71 because the result of this that I'd print looked like what I want. But I think the array is the wrong size and that this is why I can't parse it in the `loop()` function.

**What is the good, nice, clear, precise way to do this, please?** I have tried so many wrong things I'm running out of ideas.

## Second problem is:

If I replace

```
char *result;
result[71] = ']';
```

by `result = "[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]";`
And then print `is_free`, I get random values like:

```
91
49
44
32
48
44
32
48
44
32
48
44
32
48
```

etc.

So my guess is either I'm just not using ArduinoJson properly, either I'm not looking at the value at the right place. **I'm looking for insights about that**

Thanks for reading and the future eventual help!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with JSON. If you know that you're always going to get values that fit in an unsigned int then just send a count of values and then the values themselves, all as bytes.

Comment: I tried that and think it is a good idea, though I'm pretty sure I messed something up because I got some weird numbers. Anyways, if ever I try again without JSON, I'll update my question! thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues, but the main problem is the fact that function `send_request` returns a pointer to a local variable. Variable `result` is located in a stack frame that probably gets overwritten by the stack frame of whatever comes next (I guess function `loop`); hence the garbage you witnessed.

A quick and dirty solution is to replace:

```
char result[100];
```

by:

```
static char result[100];
```

This moves `result` to a dedicated piece of memory that is not reclaimed until your program finishes.

Parsing might fail because you never terminate your string; however this may no longer be a problem after the fix above (static variables are initialized with nulls). But just to be sure, add this command just before calling `parseArray`:

```
result[72] = '\0';
```

Other issues:

- <strike>Part of your code is missing; where is the main function calling `setup`, `send_request` and `loop`?</strike> Thanks for the explanation.
- `while(1);` is an infinite loop that will do nothing but turn your Arduino into a toaster; is that intentional?
- <strike>`long is_free = result[i];` should probably be `long is_free = root[i];`?</strike> Thanks for changing your code accordingly; I am pretty sure this will resolve problem #2.

Comment: `main()` is provided by the Arduino libraries; it calls `setup()` once and `loop()` repeatedly.

Comment: I tried to change `char result[100]` to `static char result[100]`, it didn't change anything.
Also arduino runs itself the setup and loop function and I edited my code because I cut some code that was supposed to be here

Comment: @nnaelle: I fixed problem #2 for you, didn't I? If problem #1 persists, then there's another bug. Debugging is going to be a lot harder if you don't get rid of your [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable) first; _please_ make the string buffer static. See also my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanations! I was missing the \0 and declared the array result at the very beginning of my code so it's always accessible.
I also have deleted the while(1) and nothing changed so that's good!
Thanks again. I'll update my post with the final code!