# Memory error - Simple XOR encryption in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf, return-value

I am having some memory issues with printing hex in the following format: \xAA\xAB\xDC using my encryption routine.

I did some modifications, using `snprintf()` and `strcat()` in an attempt to fix the output and it worked to some degree.

This is the function I originally started out with, which is probably better than my modified version.

```
char *encrypt(char key, const char *a) {
    char *output = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
    bzero(output, strlen(a)+1);
    strcpy(output, a);
    char *tmp = output;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; tmp[i] != 0; i++) {
        tmp[i] = key ^ tmp[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

My current progress is as follows:

```
char *encrypt(char key, const char *a) 
{
    char buf[256];
    char *tmp = a;
    int i;
    int *k;

    for (i = 0; tmp[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        char temp[10];
        k = key ^ tmp[i];
        snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%s", k);
        strcat(buf, temp);
    }
    return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argv[1] == NULL){
        printf("Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
    }
    else printf("Encrypted string: %s\n", encrypt(0xEB, argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to fix the memory issue, and if the code can be improved I would appreciate that a lot.

Comment: `if (argv[1] == 0)` --> `if (argv[1] ==  NULL )`

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable)

Comment: Your `snprintf` there is very strange indeed. `key ^ tmp[i]` will give you the char itself. There is no need to format it with `sprintf`. In C, the only difference between a "character" and a "number" is in how you display it to the user. In memory it's all the same.

Comment: Please tell me where does the encryption occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
int *k;
k = key ^ tmp[i];
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%s", k);
```

use this:

```
unsigned char k;
k = key ^ tmp[i];
snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "\\x%02X", k);
```

Note that you also have other changes to make regarding `buf`.  Firstly you never initialize it, so you are appending to junk.  And you never check that you didn't overflow it.

Also you attempt to return this from a function, however, since it is a local variable, it ceases to exist when the function returns.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/returning-an-array-using-c) for some suggestions of how to get freshly-written string out of a function. You could use `malloc(256)` in the same vein as your first attempt (and remember to replace `sizeof buf` with the mallocated length, in the `snprintf` call).

---

It'd be more robust to use `unsigned char` instead of `char` for both the key and the message. An example of the issues is that on x86 or x64, `char` has a range of `-128` to `127` so when you supply `0xEB` (i.e. `235`) this is an out-of-range assignment which is not well-defined.

But on common systems you will get away with using `char` because they tend to define out-of-range assignment by using 2's complement and truncating excess bits, which works in your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I performed the changes, but unfortunately, I still got the same result. I am not quite sure what is causing it. 

Output of encrypted string 'hello': ▒▒CA\x83\x8E\x87\x87\x

Comment: Thank you @M.M, that did it :-)

Comment: @AlcheemyRS updated my answer to include that info about buf.

Answer (score 3):

The primary issue, in your code, `buf` is local to the function `encrypt()`. So you may not return the array from the function. Once the function finishes, the array will cease to exist and the returned address will be invalid. If the returned value is ued in the caller, it will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to define `buf` as a pointer and allocate dynamic memory using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family. Also, you need to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the memory, once the usage is over.

That said,

- you have defined `k` to be a pointer but did not allocate memory to it.
- `k = key ^ tmp[i];` seems meaningless, maybe you meant `*k = key ^ tmp[i];`
- `%s` expects a pointer to `char` array (null-terminated) as argument. From that point, `snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%s", k);` also looks wrong. What you need is `snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%d", *k);` to print the `int` value.

Comment: And `int *k;` then used as a char pointer in `snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%s", k);`. Even the format `"\\x%s"` is wrong...

Comment: I think he meant `int k;`, but when using `snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%s", k);` he got an error of pointer required, so he changed the declaration, ignoring all the bunch of warnings issued by the compiler. It should have been `int k;` and `snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "\\x%x", k);`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have added the code I started out with to the main post for reference. 

Will look into your suggestions.