# How to implement the c malloc/realloc functions properly?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, systems-programming

I am writing my own OS and had to implement my own malloc realloc functions. However I think that what I have written may not be safe and may also cause a memory leak because the variable isn't really destroyed, its memory is set to zero, but the variable name still exists. Could someone tell me if there are any vulnerabilities in this code? The project will be added to github soon as its finished under user subado512.

Code:

```
 void * malloc(int nbytes)
{
    char variable[nbytes];
    return &variable;
}
void * free(string s) {
    s= (string)malloc(0);
    return &s;
}

void memory_copy(char *source, char *dest, int nbytes) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nbytes; i++) {
        *(dest + i) = *(source + i);             //    dest[i] = source[i]
    }
}
void *realloc(string s,uint8_t i) {
    string ret;
    ret=(string)malloc(i);
    memory_copy(s,ret,i);
    free(s);
    return &ret;
}
```

Context in which code is used : Bit of pseudo code to increase readability

```
    string buffstr = (string) malloc(200);
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while(reading)

    {
        buffstr=(string)realloc(buffstr,i+128);
        buffstr[i]=readinput();
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have a long way to go before you have a real OS.

Comment: Your `free()` function doesn't inspire confidence in your understanding of C.

Comment: Yeah your right, I have no idea, I started programming in higher level languages. Only know c because of c++. I am forced to use c because it is an OS. Wish I could use golang or something like that.

Comment: There are many beginner mistakes in this code and most of it does not make any sense. To begin with, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable). And are you programming in C or C++? It looks like C++ strings.

Comment: A readme in the topic: https://github.com/emeryberger/Malloc-Implementations

Comment: The string is : typedef char *string, so no it isn't a c++ string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour on your using the pointer returned by your `malloc` is *undefined*: you are returning the address of an array with automatic storage duration.

As a rough start, consider using a `static` `char` array to model your memory pool, and return segments of this back to the caller; building up a table of that array that is currently in use. Note that you'll have to do clever things with *alignment* here to guarantee that the returned `void*` meets the alignment requirements of *any* type. `free` will then be little more than your releasing a record in that table.

Do note that the memory management systems that a typical C runtime library uses are very sophisticated. With that in mind, do appreciate that your undertaking may be little more than a good programming exercise.

Comment: A char array that doesn't have allocated storage duration can only be aliased by a character type. In other words it cannot and it should not be used as arbitrary memory.

Comment: @2501: that's true of any type... what do you propose to use? `static union { unsigned char c; int i; long l; long long ll; double d; long double ld; void *p; void (*fun)(); } array[MEMORY_POOL_SIZE];` ?

Comment: Obviously allocated storage duration should be used.

Comment: Then you're sort of back where you started ;-)

Comment: @2501 quote from the standard?

Comment: @n.m.: I'm not sure how helpful that will be. In fact, I'm of the opinion that it's *impossible* to write `malloc` in standard C. I'll try to dig out a citation for that.

Comment: @Bathsheba it may not be possible to write a *portable* implementation, but if you know how to align stuff on your platform, why not?

Comment: @n.m. Indeed: you can simply nick the relevant code from the standard C library that ships with your compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba that code doesn't have to be in C, and if it is, it can contain UB.

Comment: @n.m. ISO:IEC 9899:201X 6.5 Expressions 7

Comment: @n.m. Absolutely. If you don't want a *portable* implementation then the gloves can come off.

Comment: @2501 Don't see anything about allocated storage duration there, care to elaborate?

Comment: @2501 nevermind found it (allocated objects have no declared type)