# A type for arbitrary memory in C

Tags: c

This is in reference to this question

[How to implement the c malloc/realloc functions properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951255/how-to-implement-the-c-malloc-realloc-functions-properly/38951308#38951308)

where the accepted answer mentions that a `char` array can be used to model a pool of arbitrary memory.

However one of the comments to that accepted answer states

> A char array that doesn't have allocated storage duration can only be
>   aliased by a character type. In other words it cannot and it should
>   not be used as arbitrary memory

Is this correct? If so, then what could be used? I'd like to avoid using `alloc` or any specific OS calls - so I'm symmetrical with that question.

Comment: A char array is fine to use, in fact [memory pools](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/epanet-haskell-2.0.12.4/src/mempool.c) are implemented using character arrays.

Comment: Don't the comments that follow this one answer your question?

Comment: I actually don't know what that means ;-) (Exit, walking backwards into a corner).

Comment: `unsigned char` which is `byte`/`uint8_t`. The other option is `void *`.

Comment: @P45Imminent the shortest answer is that it has to do with alignment requirements. The values returned from `malloc` and `calloc` are pointers that are guaranteed to be usable as pointers to any data type (as long as the allocated space is big enough). However, if you have an array defined as `char data[128];` you cannot safely cast `data` to a `Widget*` because `Widget` may have stronger alignment requirements.

Comment: Hum. How does `malloc` *know* what to do in the `Widget` case? Surely `malloc` must return the a pointer satisfying the "lowest common multiple" alignment - I can trivially steal that code for use with my char[] pool?

Comment: Usually pointer arithmetics lets you guaranty alignment, however, this might hinder performance when performed for every allocation. In a memory allocator I wrote ([a play thing you can find here](https://github.com/boazsegev/bscrypt/blob/7eb1d60c8bf8b82b39961a79d4dd20312b11b9f3/src/bscrypt/unused/mempool.c)) memory we pooled a few pages at a time (using `mmap`). Pages are naturally page-size aligned. When I divided them up, I always made sure that the minimal division was performed according to my alignment requirement (which was 8 bytes)... this way, I avoided runtime pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write a conformant implementation of malloc in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515179/is-it-possible-to-write-a-conformant-implementation-of-malloc-in-c)

Comment: @P45Imminent To expand on my comment: as others have pointed out the main problem is whether types may alias. A type char may only be aliased by a character type, i.e. any access trough a non-character type is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue he pointed out was that if you allocate a `char` type array statically and then compile your library with a modern, desktop-like C compiler like gcc, you cannot easily convert the contents of that area to another type. Because then the compiler would perform optimizations based on pointer aliasing and screw everything up, see ["the strict aliasing rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Simply assure that your compiler does not use strict aliasing and you'll be fine. For example, none of the common embedded systems compilers on the market does this.

With gcc you'd compile as `-fno-strict-aliasing`. Might be good to always enable warnings for code that would cause such problems `-Wstrict-aliasing`.

As a side note, `uint8_t` makes far more sense to use as generic type, because unlike `char`, it is completely unambiguous: it has no signedness and the size is well-known.

Comment: Down vote for what? Calling out that gcc is quite unsuitable for hardware-related programming because of all aggressive optimizations. It is my favourite compiler, but it is still true.

Comment: (not my downvote) I think OP could use more clarification on what a statically allocated array is.

Comment: The size of char is well known (it's 1) and uint8_t is entirely optional. Signedness is irrelevant as you are not doing any arithmetic.

Comment: @n.m. The size of char is unknown, it is 1 byte but x bits. Signedness is very relevant as soon as you actually use the variables for any purpose. In particular, implicit integer promotion may cause all manner of bugs in case `char` is a signed type and data is stored in the sign bits. Using `char` for any other purpose than storing characters is sloppy programming, there is no reason to. `stdint.h` is mandatory for all implementations, no idea why you think it isn't. See 7.20.1.

Comment: @Lundin A size of an object is a number of bytes it occupies (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators), Thus a type which occupies exactly one byte is relevant. Bits are unimportant as long as you don't access individual bits of an object through a `char` value, which you shouldn't. Size of `uint8_t` in bytes is unknown. It's permitted to access any type via a value of type `char` (6.5 Expressions/7), no bugs related to signedness of `char` are mentioned, but you can use `unsigned char` if you want. No such permission for `uint8_t`. `stdint_t` is mandatory,`uint8_t` is not, see 7.20.1.1/3.

Comment: @n.m. If you're trying to say that uint8_t may not be a synonym for a character type, and thus may not alias any type, then this is correct. Just a minor mistake, size of uint8_t is always 1 as it must have exactly 8 bits.

Comment: @Lundin uint8_t may be defined as an extended integer type and not a character type. In this case it may not serve as a 'generic' type. (It is also only available if CHAR_BIT == 8.)

Answer (score 2):

There are different problems around. First as shown by @Magisch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968769/3545273) the related question was returning a *dangling* pointer causing Undefined Behaviour and generally execution errors.

The second one is related to the @^*# (censorship here) strict aliasing rule. Common compilers produce correct code when you use a character array as a large buffer to *allocate* any type from it, provided you ensure correct alignment. After all, this is the way they have to implement the `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free` routines. And as they are part of the *hosted environment* (C standard library), the compiler developpers are not masochist enough to fordib that usage.

But the C standard is a bit more strict here. You should read my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608659/3545273) to a similar question and particularly @EOF's comment to it:

> You cannot parcel of parts of an object declared as char [] into objects of other types (except character types), because they do have a declared type... which means technically you can't implement malloc() in pure C

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing refers to [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) that governs how the compiler is allowed to use registers. If you have pointers of different type referring to the same memory location, then writing done through one pointer type may not be noticed when reading through the other pointer type because the compiler is allowed to cache the data in registers.

When you implement a memory pool, this problem is usually moot, because the pool implementation doesn't read/write to the memory.

If you want arbitrary types, then the safest bet is a union. Not only will it "beat" the strict aliasing rule, it will also ensure correct alignment. Remember that `malloc` and friends ensure alignment suitable for any type while `auto` doesn't.

Comment: The problem with an `union`, is that it may be hard to guess in advance all the possible types (think about structs...)

Comment: Just nitpicking: `malloc` and friends ensure alignment suitable for any type *with a fundamental alignment requirement* (quoting C11 here, 6.2.8 Alignment of objects / 7.22.3 Memory management functions).  An implementation is at liberty to provide types with *extended* alignment (`> _Alignof( max_align_t )`). Windows, [for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycsb6wwf.aspx), has the SSE types `__m128` and `__m256`, with a `malloc` that does 64bit alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is alignment. On processors that have alignment restrictions, a `char` array may not start at an address suitable for storing larger objects, like `int` or `double`.

So to be safe, you need to make sure the `char` array is aligned properly for any type.
If you're using a C11 compiler, then you can force alignment like this

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

_Alignas(max_align_t) char buffer[SIZE];
```

For older compilers, `__attribute__((aligned(SIZE)))` may be a solution. Otherwise, you need to look for a `#pragma` that forces alignment.

And as discussed in various comments/answers, you should definitely disable the strict aliasing optimization with the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option. If that option (or the equivalent) doesn't exist, then you need to determine the optimization level that relies on the strict aliasing rule, and only use a lower optimization level.

Comment: That will only align `buffer` in whole, but when used as a heap, care would need to be taken to ensure that all allocations inside the heap are aligned as well. Plus OP's question is in the scope of writing his own OS, so `stdalign.h` isn't available.

Comment: @Ext3h Good point about making sure that all allocations are aligned (typically done by rounding up requests to a multiple of `sizeof(max_align_t)`). Disagree with the second comment. If the OP writes the OS in C, and compiles it with a C11 compiler, then `stdalign.h` *is* available. If the OP writes his/her own OS, and then implements his/her own compiler for said OS, then whether or not `stdalign.h` is available is up to the OP.