# C - function returning a pointer to a local variable

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Consider the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *abc(); // this function returns a pointer of type int

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = abc();
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}

int *abc()
{
    int i = 45500, *p;
    p = &i;
    return p;
}
```

**Output:**

45500

I know according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable) this type of behavior is undefined. But why i am getting correct value everytime i run the program.

Comment: Because undefined behaviour is allowed to do that. By the way, I don't see anything wrong with this question. Upvoted.

Comment: Its because your program is very simple. Try to insert a call to some other function between calls to `abc()` and `printf()`

Comment: So what? "Undefined" doesn't mean "random"...

Comment: Add this, immediately after the call to `abc()` and before the existing `printf`: `printf("Test string %d %d %d %d\n", 1, 2, 3, 4)`. Then see what happens :)

Comment: Call *abc()* then call *def()* and after check what *p* points to... You could make *i* static, as long as there is no reentrance issue... (e.g. threads modifying `*p` ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you call `abc` it "marks" a region at the top of the stack as the place where it will write all of its local variables. It does that by moving the pointer that indicates where the top of stack is. That region is called the stack frame. When the function returns, it indicates that it does not want to use that region anymore by moving the stack pointer to where it was originally. As a result, if you call other functions afterwards, they will reuse that region of the stack for their own purposes. But in your case, you haven't called any other functions yet. So that region of the stack is left in the same state.

All the above explain the behavior of your code. It is not necessary that all C compilers implement functions that way and therefore **you should not rely on that behavior**.

Comment: This is *very* implementation specific.

Comment: Yes, I am only explaining the behavior to satisfy his curiosity.

Comment: As an example Keil C compiler for i8051: It allocates locals in data segment by building a calling tree at link time, so stack is used only to pass control

Comment: @Serge: How does it handle recursion?

Comment: @EOF Well, it has a special keyword `recursion` (or `-ive`, I can't recall) to declare a function as a recursive one. Then it maintains an software stack to copy locals on that stack upon second entry to that function. TBH, they did a good job taking to account capabilities of that mCPU

Comment: Generally speaking, such compilers (same as with those for Microchip 8 bit ones) don't allow recursion (they detect it at link time). They will also often complain about calling the same function from background and ISRs (i.e. no such thing as re-entrant code)

Comment: @kdopen: C *requires* recursion to be possible: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 11 Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain
of other functions.* If the compiler doesn't allow recursion, it's not a C-compiler.

Comment: @EOF when Keil released the MCS51 comiler `C11` did not exist yet)

Comment: Which is where the spec meets reality. I've had this discussion with others. Sometimes, there is no way to create a conformant compiler for a given chip architecture. That doesn't mean an almost-compliant compiler isn't better than raw assembler. Also, those compilers are usually C90

Comment: @Serge: C99 draft standard n1256: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 11 Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain
of other functions.* This is not new.

Comment: @EOF I used that compiler in the beginning of 00's. Anyway, it is a history now.

Comment: @Serge the one I'm talking about is still available and still in use: "All the MPLAB XC compilers conform to the ANSI X3.159-1989 Standard for programming
languages (with the exception of the MPLAB XC8 compiler’s inability to allow
recursion, as mentioned in the footnote). This is commonly called the C89 Standard.
Some features from the later standard, C99, are also supported. "

Comment: @kdopen I doubt you would find anything significantly newer for MCS51, so that Keil's compiler is still available in a sense. At least I still have it :)

Comment: @EOF: Does the Standard specify any minimum depth that an implementation must support without UB?

Comment: @supercat: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: @EOF: Some implementations that statically allocate stacks will only run programs that can be guaranteed not to die from a stack overflow.  While there are purposes for which recursion is needed, a guarantee that a program will work without stack overflow seems more useful than saying that an implementation must "try" to run a program, but can do anything it likes if it overflows an arbitrarily-small stack [the "one program" rule could be satisfied by a contrived program whose stack usage could be optimized away].

Comment: Suggestion: "you should not rely on that behavior." -> "you should not rely on that behavior, which is undefined per the standard."

Answer (score 2):

Well, undefined behavior is, undefined. You can never **rely** on UB (*or on an output of a program invoking UB*).

Maybe, *just maybe* in your environment and for *your* code, the memory location allocated for the local variable is not *reclaimed* by the OS and still *accessible*, but there's no guarantee that it will have the same behavior for any other platform.

Comment: what's UB ?? pls define

Comment: @Cody UB -> undefined behavior.