# C Shallow Copy Confusion

Tags: c, struct, reference, shallow-copy

Edit: Fixed bug that was mentioned in the comments and the problem still exists, so this question isn't really a duplicate - just that my C programming skill is not very good at this point, the solution given below answers the question and doesn't address the local variable bug.

Warning: fairly new to C

I understand that when we assign a struct to another struct, a shallow copy is performed. However, I was unable to understand the result of why this happened:

Suppose the following where I try to initialize a struct's, call it a Type2 struct's, Type1 member by using the assignment operator, then a shallow copy should have been performed. This means that the address of the Type2 member is copied:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t someVal;
} Type1

typedef struct {
    Type1 grid[3][3];
} Type2

//Constructor for Type2 "objects"
Type2 Type2_Constructor(void) {
    Type1 empty = {.value = o}
    Type2 newType2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            //Shallow copy empty struct
            newType2.grid[i][j] = empty;
        }
    return newType2;
}

int main (void) {    
    Type2 type2Object = Type2_Constructor();   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("%u",type2OBject.grid[i][j].value);
            printf("\n\r%p\n\r",&(type2Object.grid[i][j].value));
            printf("\n\r");
        }   
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect to see:

```
0
0xMemoryLocation

0
0xMemoryLocation

0
0xMemoryLocation

.
.
.
```

In fact, what I am seeing is something like this where the address is incremented by 2 bytes:

```
0
0x7fff57eaca18

0
0x7fff57eaca1a

0
0x7fff57eaca1c

0
0x7fff57eaca1e

0
0x7fff57eaca20

.
.
.
```

Since shallow copy is supposed to copy the address directly, why are &(type2Object.grid[i][j].value) different?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: read again what shallow copy is. Hint: the difference between shallow and deep copy is relevant only when you have pointer members, which you don't have.

Comment: UB - you can not return pointer to local data: `Type2 * newType2Ptr = &newType2; return newType2Ptr;`

Comment: Returning that pointer is the cause of the bug(s).

Comment: Fixed that bug in the code, still same problem so I am guessing that bug didn't affect anything before. I tested this by verifying that whatever default value I set for Type1.val, it would be printed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of *pointers*. If you have two pointer variables of the same type, lets call them `a` and `b`. If you do `a = b` you do a *shallow copy*, you copy only the actual pointer `b` to `a`, not the memory that `b` points to. This means that both `a` and `b` points to the same memory.

A deep copy would copy the contents of what `b` points to, into some newly allocated memory. A deep copy would lead to `a` and `b` point to different memory.

---

Taking your structure:

```
typedef struct {
    Type1 grid[3][3];
} Type2
```

If you have

```
Type2 a;
Type2 b = { ... };  // Some initialization, not relevant exactly what
```

then an assignment

```
a = b;   // Copy structure b to a
```

This is a shallow copy. ***But*** because the data of the structure is an array the whole array is copied, and it *looks* like a deep copy.

If there was a pointer inside the structure only the pointer would be copied. Another example, with a new structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char *pointer;
} Type3;

Type3 a;
Type3 b = { "abcd" };

a = b;

printf("a.pointer = %s\n", a.pointer);
printf("b.pointer = %s\n", b.pointer);
```

The code above will print the same string for both `a.pointer` and `b.pointer`. But it is the *same* pointer. If we add a new printout of the pointers:

```
printf("a.pointer = %p\n", (void *) a.pointer);
printf("b.pointer = %p\n", (void *) b.pointer);
```

The above two lines would after the assignment print the same value. Both pointers would be pointing to the same memory. It is a shallow copy.

Also, a structure assignment like the ones shown above is no different thatn doing e.g.

```
memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof a);
```

---

Actually I think your confusion is that you think referencing another structure is like references in Java or C# or C++, when it's not.

Each element in the `grid` array in the `Type2` structure is a unique instance of the `Type1` structure. And as unique instances they all occupy different memory, leading to the addresses you print being all different.

When you do

```
newType2.grid[i][j] = empty;
```

you copy the contents of the `empty` structure instance, into the structure instance `newType2.grid[i][j]`. Using the `memcpy` call shown above, what the assignment does is really

```
memcpy(&newType2.grid[i][j], &empty, sizeof newType2.grid[i][j]);
```

It does a bitwise copy of the contents of `empty`.

---

About the difference between a pointer an an array, consider the following definitions:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *p = a;
```

In memory it would look something like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
^
|
+---+     
| p |
+---+
```

That is, you have the array and its contents taking up space enough for four `int` values. Then you have the pointer `p` which points to the first element in the array (arrays decays to pointers to their first element, in the case of the array `a` above, using `a` as a pointer is equal to `&a[0]`).

Comment: Sorry to bring this up so late but I was re-reading this answer and noticed the sentence "But because the data of the structure is an array the whole array is copied, and it looks like a deep copy." and "If there was a pointer inside the structure only the pointer would be copied." But I thought C arrays are just pointers, so if today I had Type1 * grid[3]  then that would be a shallow copy?

Comment: @lpbug A pointer is something which *points* to some chunk of memory. An array *is* a chunk of memory. Added a section about it at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be misunderstanding what shallow/deep copy is. A shallow copy would copy each member (or do a bitwise copy if you will). A deep copy would also copy **the owned resources** of the struct.

Let's start with a simple example:

```
struct X {
   int val;
};

X x1 = {24};
X x2 = {42};

x1 = x2;
```

Yes, the build-in assignment operator operator `=` does perform a shallow copy. That means the above is equivalent with:

```
x1.val = x2.val;
```

In this case as `X` has **no external resources it owns** so it is also considered a deep copy because everyting that `x2` owns is copied to `x1`. This is a consequence of the fact that `X` does not own any external resources.

The importance of shallow/deep copy comes into play when `X` would own an **external resource**/ E.g.:

```
struct X {
   int *my_very_own_external_value;
};

X x1, x2;
x1.my_very_own_external_value = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x1.my_very_own_external_value = 24;

x2.my_very_own_external_value = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x2.my_very_own_external_value = 42;
```

A shallow copy would be this:

```
x1 = x2;
```

This would be equivalent to this:

```
x1.my_very_own_external_value  = x2.my_very_own_external_value;
```

Which if you understand pointers means that `x1` lost the address of it's allocated memory (who holds `24`) and now both `x1` and `x2` have pointers to the memory allocated for `x2`, i.e. the one that stores `42`;

If you want a deep copy you would need to write:

```
free(x1.my_very_own_external_value);
x1.my_very_own_external_value  = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x1.my_very_own_external_value  = *x2.my_very_own_external_value;
```

Now you have copied the memory (external resource) that `x2` owns externally.

---

disclaimer: I might have written in C++ style

Answer (score 0):

You code has a bug:

```
//Constructor for Type2 "objects"
Type2 * Type2_Constructor(void) {
    Type1 empty = ...;
    Type2 newType2;
    ... do something ...
    Type2 * newType2Ptr = &newType2;
    return newType2Ptr;
}
```

*newType2* is a local variable - a struct that is defined on stack.
Then you are returning its address to the calling function.
Once the you exit the *Type2_Constructor* function, its stack is no longer in your hands.

When you print values from this area you get all sorts of things (you'd hope to get a core dump, but sadly, that's not always the case).

Comment: I see your point, could you offer a way to resolve this bug? I've been looking at other questions regarding constructor/factory functions and have not found any satisfactory answers.

Comment: I fixed that bug in the edit and the same problem still exists, so I think I just lucked out and the stack wasn't overwritten upon return.

Comment: Re. access to local variable of another function - as pointed out, you can find the answer here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable