# Conversion from pointer to normal vector works inside main but not when returned from a function

Tags: c++

```
int main() 
{

    vector<int> *v2, v3;
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(17);
    v.push_back(6);
    vector<vector<int> *> v1;
    v1.push_back(&v);
    v2 = v1.at(0);
    v3 = *v2;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = v3.begin(); i != v3.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works as expected but when i try to initialize vector from a list of vector pointers returned by a function gives me an error

```
vector<vector<int> *> func()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(17);
    v.push_back(6);
    vector<vector<int> *> v1;
    v1.push_back(&v);
    return v1;
}
int main() 
{

    vector<int> *v2, v3;
    vector<vector<int> *> v1;
    v1 = func();
    v2 = v1.at(0);
    v3 = *v2;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = v3.begin(); i != v3.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand what is the problem in the above code snippet. Kindly advise.
Error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Why don't you use `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function is returning a vector that contains a pointer to another **locally-defined** vector. The latter is destroyed at the end of the function, so your pointers in the outer vector are dangling.

```
vector<vector<int> *> func()
{
    vector<int> v; // this object is destroyed at the end of the function
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(17);
    v.push_back(6);
    vector<vector<int> *> v1;
    v1.push_back(&v); // DANGER DANGER the pointer &v will dangle
    return v1; 
}
```

Don't use pointers inside vectors unless it is strictly necessary (even in that case prefer to use smart pointers as they keep track of the ownership). You can simply use a `vector<vector<int>>` or a 1D vector and map from 1D to 2D and vice-versa. The latter option is the preferred one since it guarantees that all elements are in a contiguous memory zone and hence it is cache-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
vector<int> v;
//...
v1.push_back(&v);
return v1;
```

You take an address of the local variable `v` and return it to the caller. After this line:

```
v1 = func();
```

the pointer in `v1[0]` will point to `v`, which does not exist anymore, as it has gone out of scope (`func` function) and was destroyed. Dereferencing this pointer is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so you get badalloc.

There are at least two solutions for this problem. The first is to declare `v1` as

```
vector<vector<int>> v1;
```

so you will return a *copy* of `v`, placed to `v1[0]`, not a pointer to it.

Another way is to leave `v1` declared with pointer and allocate `v` on heap:

```
vector<int> *v = new vector<int>;
v->push_back(2);
v->push_back(1);
v->push_back(17);
v->push_back(6);
vector<vector<int> *> v1;
v1.push_back(v);
```

so contents of `v` will not be destroyed after `v` goes out of scope. But you should not forget to delete it manually after usage, or you'll get memory leak.