# The array is filling with the last element

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am trying to fill an array (char*).

When I am filling the array, I make a print to display elements and it is OK.

But, after that, when I try to use the array away (in the `main()` function), always it is filling with the last element.

```
typedef struct Device {
char *adr_mac;
char *rssi;
} Device; 

Device * devices[6];
int array_length = 6;

void *changeRssi( void *tab)
{
int h = 0;
srand(time(NULL));

int rssi = 0;
char ch[2] = "";

while(1){
   sleep(10);
printf("\n\n  $$$ Changing RSSI of devices ...\n\n");
for (h = 0; h < array_length; h++)
{

    rssi = generate_rssi(10,99);
    sprintf(ch, "%d", rssi);
    devices[h] -> rssi = ch;
    printf("new rssi = %s\n\n", devices[h] -> rssi);
}  
}

}
```

Comment: can you also post your main function as well or at least the relevant part that makes use of your array?

Comment: The core problem here is that you have an array of pointers. You never do a hard copy of the data, but point at local data. Numerous duplicates about those issues can be found all over SO.

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, see [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable) and [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to mention here.

**First,** It appears, your `rssi` value takes two `char`s (range 10-99), but, for `sprintf()`, you're supplying a buffer of size 2, so you're one element short, or, in other words, you're off-by-one regarding the array bounds.

As per the `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.6, `sprintf()` definition

> [....]A null character is written
>   at the end of the characters written; [...]

but, in your case, the space is not there, so array boundary overrun happens which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: you'll be needing an array of size 3.

**Second** : in case of a statement like `devices[h] -> rssi = ch;`, the content of `ch` is not copied to `devices[h] -> rssi`, rather, the `devices[h] -> rssi` points to `ch`. In this case, `ch` being a local variable, goes out of scope when the function returns, so any later access to `devices[h] -> rssi` would be an invalid memory access, which, once again, cause UB.

Solution: You need to allocate memory using allocator functions like `malloc()` and family to `devices[h] -> rssi` and the copy the content of `ch`, or, use `strdup()`.

Comment: This is a minor bug compared to setting global pointers to point at local arrays, though. It would seem that the OP has a fundamental misunderstand about how C strings work.

Comment: @Lundin Sir, with all the due respect, i fail to see how an array overrun is a _minor_ bug. However, I'll update my answer to include the other issue, as well, thanks.

Comment: Yes, well there's too much wrong with the original code to salvage something from it. It has to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: @Lundin Agree, also updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , thank you, your answer solved my problem .