# Can not Print string via function return value?

Tags: c, string, printf, return-value, function-calls

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

char *in() { 
    char a[10]; 
    scanf("%s",a); 
    return (a); 
} 

int main () { 
    char *a; a=in(); 
    printf("\n%s",a); 
    return (0); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 return (a);
```

is an attempt to return the address of a local variable. In the caller, any usage (*attempt to access*) of the address will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the memory address is *invalid*.

After the function returns, the local variables inside the function will cease to exist, their lifetime expires. So, the addresses corresponding to those variables (*objects*) becomes invalid. As per `C11`, chapter §6.2.4

> [...] If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

*Note: That said, my personal addition::* `return` is a keyword, please don't make it look like a function.

**Solution:** You need to make sure that the lifetime of the variable of which the address is being returned, supersede the function scope, so you can either

- use `malloc()` and family to allocate memory
- use a variable with `static` storage.

Comment: Instead of repeatedly answering very common FAQs, how about starting to close them as duplicates instead? This question has 2 canonical duplicates: [Pointer to local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/pointer-to-local-variable) when the OP doesn't know what they are doing and [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) when the OP knows that this is wrong but wants to know why it "seems to work".

Answer (score 0):

Do not return local variable pointer. Use global instead or static.

```
char *in() { 
    static char a[10]; 
    scanf("%s",a); 
    return (a); 
} 

int main () { 
    char *a; a=in(); 
    printf("\n%s",a); 
    return (0); 
}
```