# C - dynamic matrix allocation: something doesn't make sense to me

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, dynamic, allocation

I was wondering, why does this work

```
// read n as matrix dimension, then:

int* M;
M = (int*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));

// cycle through each "cell" in the matrix and read a number with

scanf("%d", &M[i * n + j]);
```

and this doesn't?

```
// read n as matrix dimension, then:

int** M;
M = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));

// cycle through each "cell" in the matrix and read a number with

scanf ("%d", &M[i][j]);
```

I just don't get it. In both cases they should be double pointers, am I right?

Comment: You are wrong. (Well, if you weren't you could not have asked this.) The second is, no matter its dimensions, a pointer to an *array of pointers*. Which are not allocated yet.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397733/841108) approach: matrix as an abstract data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1 :-**

```
int* M;
M = (int*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
```

Here memory is allocated for `M` which is single pointer. Let's say you want to store `5` integers into that memory. So it looks like

```
    -------------------------------
   |  10  |  20  | 30  | 40  | 50  |
    -------------------------------
  M  M[0]   M[1]   M[2]  m[3]  M[4] <--- Its a 1D array, only one row of 5 int
```

**Case 2 :-**

```
int **M;
M = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));


 M[0][0]  M[0][1] 
        |         |     |    |   .......    |       |    <---- If below one is not done then how will you store the numbers into these  
        -----------      -----              --------- 
             |            |         |          |
            M[0]         M[1]      M[2] ....  M[4]      <---  didn't allocated memory for these rows or 1D array
             |            |         |          |
             -----------------------------------   
                             |  
                             M                          <----  allocated memory for this
```

It doesn't work because `M` is double pointer and you allocated memory only for `M`, you didn't allocated memory for `M[row]`. thats why below statement didn't work.

```
 scanf ("%d", &M[i][j]);
```

So to make it work first Allocate the memory for `M` as you did

```
M = malloc(row*sizeof(*M)); /* row indicates no of rows */
```

and then allocate for each row

```
for(int index = 0 ;index < row;index++) {
M[index] = malloc(col * sizeof(*M[index])); /* col indicates number of columns */
}
```

And scan the matrix input

```
for(int index = 0 ;index < row;index++) {
   for(int sub_index = 0 ;sub_index < col; sub_index++)
      scanf("%d",&M[index][sub_index]);
   }
```

and once work is done with matrix free the dynamically allocated memory using `free()` for each row to **avoid memory leakage**.

Comment: Although `M = malloc(row*sizeof(int*));` works when `M` is a `int **`.  `M = malloc(row * sizeof *M);` works when `M` is any pointer type.  Easier to code, review and maintain.

Comment: perfect @chux `sizeof(*M)` makes more sense to me, it works for any pointer type. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1):

`int **` is supposed to point to an `int*`. Here you have allocated some memory - to be precise `sizeof(int)*rows*cols` bytes and then you use `M[i]` etc. Here `M[i]` which is basically `*(M+i)`  we will access `i*sizeof(int*)` offset from the one address returned by `malloc` but you allocated for `rows*cols` `int`'s not `int*`-s - so you will eventually access memory that you shouldn't (typically on a system where `sizeof(int*) > sizeof(int)`) which will lead you to undefined behavior.

What is the solution then? Well allocate for `int*`-s.

```
int ** M = malloc(sizeof *M * rows);
if(!M){
   perror("malloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  M[i] = malloc(sizeof *M[i] * cols);
  if(!M[i]){
     perror("malloc");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
 }
```

*For your case `rows = N` and `cols = N`.*

This will you give you a jagged array which you can access like you did. With `malloc` comes the responsibility of checking the return type of it and freeing the memory when you are done working with it. Do that.

On the first case you are accessing the allocated chunk of memory and you have realized the memory access using indices `i` and `j` to give yourself a flavor of accessing memory that you do in case of 2d array. So there is no point using double pointer here. It is legal what you did.

> *In both cases they should be double pointers*

No they shouldn't be. The first one is different than the second one. They are not in anyway indicating the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers (suggesting one `malloc` for `M` and `n` `malloc`s for the rows) are correct, but not the most efficient way to allocate a matrix. You can, however, allocate the matrix with only one `malloc` call, while still allowing you to index it by row and column with `M[i][j]`, as follows:

```
int (*M)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof *M);
```

This declares `M` as a *pointer to array of `int` with length `cols`* and requests `malloc` to allocate `rows` number of such arrays, meaning you get a single block of `rows * cols` `int`s (`sizeof *M == sizeof(int) * cols`).

When the `malloc` succeeds, you can use `M` as if it were declared as `int M[rows][cols]` so you can read into it with

```
scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);
```

It looks more complicated, but allocates `M` as one contiguous block of memory, which allows the processor to optimize access to it.

And as an added bonus you can also free it with just one call:

```
free(M);
```

This does require C99 support, or at least support for variable-length arrays, but the matrix itself is not a proper variable-length array. It is still allocated by `malloc`, but the declaration of `M` allows you to use it like one.