# Function to multiply 3x3 matrices gives wrong answer for middle column only

Tags: c

While teaching myself c, I thought it would be good practice to write a function which multiplies two 3x3 matrices and then make it more general. The function seems to calculate the correct result for the first and last columns but not the middle one. In addition, each value down the middle column is out by 3 more than the last.

For example:

```
[1 2 3]   [23  4  6]
[4 5 6] * [ 2 35  0]
[7 8 9]   [14  2 43]
```

The answer I receive is:

```
[ 69  80 135]
[190 273 282]
[303 326 429]
```

The actual answer should be:

```
[ 69  83 135]
[190 279 282]
[303 335 429]
```

Isolating the middle columns for clarity:

```
Received  Expected
   [ 80]  [ 83]
   [273]  [279]
   [326]  [335]
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mat_3x3
{
    double values [3][3];
} mat_3x3;



void SetMatrix(mat_3x3 * matrix, double vals[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            (matrix->values)[i][j] = vals[i][j];
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}



mat_3x3 MatrixMultiply(mat_3x3 * m1, mat_3x3 * m2)
{
    mat_3x3 result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            double temp = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {               
                temp += ((m1->values)[i][k] * (m2->values)[k][j]);
            }
            (result.values)[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return result;
}



void PrintMatrix(mat_3x3 * matrix)
{
    putchar('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%lf  ", (matrix->values)[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}



int main()
{
    mat_3x3 m1;
    mat_3x3 * pm1 = &m1;
    
    mat_3x3 m2;
    mat_3x3 * pm2 = &m2;
    
    double vals[3][3] = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,7,6},
        {7,8,9}
    };
    
    double vals2[3][3] = {
        {23,4,6},
        {2,35,0},
        {14,2,43}
    };
    
    SetMatrix(pm1, vals);
    SetMatrix(pm2, vals2);
    
    printf("\nm1:");
    PrintMatrix(pm1);
    printf("\nm2:");
    PrintMatrix(pm2);
        
    mat_3x3 m3 = MatrixMultiply(pm1, pm2);
    mat_3x3 * pm3 = &m3;
    printf("\nm3 = m1 * m2");
    PrintMatrix(pm3);
    
}
```

Have been working on this for a while now comparing it against other simple examples and can't find the problem, so help would be appreciated!

Also if I've done anything atrocious syntax wise etc, I'm open to any criticism on how it's written as well.

Comment: Don't print from purely math functions. Use memcpy to transfer the matrix data.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the code. The answer you think you should be getting is wrong. The answer it actually gives is what I get from doing it by hand.

Comment: Off by 3, off by 6, off by 9. Hmmmm - The same values held by the third column of the first matrix. Sounds like a missed addition to me. Each time, the result is MatrixA.colum3 too small.

Comment: The PrintMatrix(pm4) thing is a miss type, is corrected now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I've found the problem. Tried a different online calculator to check answers and it matched up fine this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While teaching myself c, I thought it would be good practice to write a function which multiplies two 3x3 matrices and then make it more general. The function seems to calculate the correct result for the first and last columns but not the middle one. In addition, each value down the middle column is out by 3 more than the last.

In practice, when coding in C, you should take care of the following issues:

- refer to a good [C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and read a good C programming book, such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)
- **floating point numbers are *not* mathematical real numbers**, see [floating-point-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/) for much more. For example, addition is associative in math, but not on a computer using [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).
- **we all make bugs** (e.g. [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) or [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)). So you need to learn how to **use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)**. I recommend [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). But you need to learn how to use it and spend a few hours reading documentation. Tools like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) are also useful (to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)) as soon as you use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).
- **recent [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) can be helpful**. I recommend [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). You should [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Be sure to spend some time in reading the documentation of your compiler. You might later consider using [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or (for precision analysis) [Fluctuat](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Eputot/fluctuat.html) or [CADNA](https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna/)
- consider having a matrix [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397733/841108). You would then easily generalize your code to "arbitrary" N*M matrixes.
- later, for [benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) purposes, you will want to use an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).  If you use GCC, you could compile your code using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O3` but then you could have surprising optimizations, see e.g. [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.
- in some cases, you could need [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Consider then using specialized libraries such as [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).
- Most computers today are [multi-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor). You could want to use [Pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) to take advantage of that with concurrent programming.
- many [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) libraries exist for scientific computations. Look at least for inspiration on [github](https://github.com/) and [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) and see also [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries). You could be interested by [GNU GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) and *study its source code* since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (and later improve it).

If you want to make serious scientific computations, you might consider switching (for expressiveness) to [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages such as [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/). If you care about making a lot of iterative computing (like in [finite element methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method)) you might switch to [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC).

### Be aware that scientific computation is a very difficult field.

Expect to spend a decade in learning it.

---

> I'm open to any criticism on how it's written as well.

> ```
>  mat_3x3 MatrixMultiply(mat_3x3 * m1, mat_3x3 * m2)
> ```

**is unusual**. Why don't you return a pointer (to a fresh memory zone obtained with [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and correctly initialized) ? That is likely to be faster (a pointer is usually 8 bytes, a 3x3 matrix takes 72 bytes to be copied) and enable you to code things like `MatrixMultiply(MatrixMultiply(M1, M2), MatrixAdd(M2, M3))`. Of course, [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/), consider using [Boehm GC](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/)) then becomes an issue. If you used [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), the system GC would be very helpful.

Comment: To be honest I just didn't think of that. Is there a particular reason it's preferable?