# Why doesn't the encryption function 'crypt()' accept my nonce although the nonce is a valid, two characters long string?

Tags: c, hash, string-concatenation, cs50, crypt

I want my program to extract the first two characters of the given hash `hash`. These first two characters represent a nonce/salt that the password was encrypted with (DES-based, `crypt()` function). The first two characters of `hash` are stored in the array `nonceAsArray[]`, which is being passed down to the function `concatenateCharacters()`, whose job is to turn these characters into a nonce of type `string` and save it in the variable `nonce` so that it can be used later on in order to encrypt a password.

The function seems to concatenate the two characters perfectly fine. However, when `nonce` is given to the `crypt()` function as an argument, it returns **null** but only, if I calculate both, `generatedHash1` and `generatedHash2`:

> Output:
>
> generatedHash1: 14dJperBYV6zU
>
> generatedHash2: (null)

However, when I exclude the calculation of the first hash `string generatedHash1 = crypt("myPassword", "14");`, my program outputs the following:

> generatedHash2: dJperBYV6zU

The `crypt()` function now seems to have accepted the value that is being stored in `nonce`. Another odd thing is that `crypt()` returns a hash without the nonce being represented in the first two characters of `generatedHash2`. The encrypted password however should be 13 characters long in total.

Fired up the debugger and checked the values that are being stored in `nonce`. I stumbled upon this:

> nonce: 0x7fffffffdd40 "14"
>
> and
>
> *nonce: 49 '1'

I assume that the first part that starts with `0x7f...` is the memmory address and next to it the value that stored at this address.

Can anyone help me understand as to why the `crypt()` function doesn't seem to accept the value in `nonce`? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could give me a hint where to look or an explenation as to why it fails.

```
(...)
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
(...)

// extract the first two characters of 'hash' (== nonce/salt)
string hash = "14dJperBYV6zU";
char nonceAsArray[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    nonceAsArray[i] = hash[i];
}

string nonce = concatenateCharacters(nonceAsArray, 2);

printf("first hash: %s\n", crypt("myPassword", "14"));
printf("second hash: %s\n", crypt("myPassword", nonce));

// connects characters to strings
string concatenateCharacters(char characters[], int arraySize)
{
    char terminator[1] = {'\0'};
    // create array that can store the password and to which the terminator can be appended (hence +1)
    char bigEnoughArray[arraySize + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        bigEnoughArray[i] = characters[i];
    }

    return strcat(bigEnoughArray, terminator);
}
```

Comment: `return strcat(bigEnoughArray, terminator);` is completely wrong because 1. returning pointer to a non-static local array, which will expire on exiting from the block it is declared. 2. `strcat` expects already null-terminated string. It is NOT for newly adding terminating null-character.

Comment: The type `string` isn't in the standard C. Please consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/how-to-access-a-local-variable-from-a-different-function-using-pointers

Comment: What the heck is `string`? Is it an obfuscated `char*`? And if, why?

Answer (score 0):

I "guess" it helps to replace this

```
string hash = "14dJperBYV6zU";
char nonceAsArray[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    nonceAsArray[i] = hash[i];
}

string nonce = concatenateCharacters(nonceAsArray, 2);
```

by

```
#define NONCE_MAX (2);

string hash = "14dJperBYV6zU";
char nonceAsArray[NONCE_MAX + 1] = ""; /* zeros out all nonceAsArray */
strncpy(nonceAsArray, hash, NONCE_MAX);
string nonce = nonceAsArray;
```