# Passing a variable to one function to another

Tags: c, string, function

Im trying to get **userInput** from one function than use it in another. When I test to see if the **char** is working in the **DetermineWhatCommand** function the first time I type characters I get the wrong output but after that the next entered string appears correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100




char * GetUserInput(){
  char userInput[MAX];
  fgets(userInput, sizeof (userInput), stdin);
  userInput[strcspn(userInput, "\n")] = '\0';

   return userInput;
}

void DetermineWhatCommand(char *userInput){
  printf(userInput);

}


int main() {

    char * userInput;
    userInput = new char[MAX];
    char exitTest[] = "exit";

    while(strcmp(exitTest, userInput) != 0){
        userInput = GetUserInput();
        DetermineWhatCommand(userInput);

   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello    //First string entered
@        //What the output in the function looks like
Hello    //Second string entered
Hello    //What the output in the function looks like
```

Comment: Using `new` in `C` instead of `C++`?

Comment: Yea thanks for the reminder, haven't used C in years.

Comment: Tempting to close it as a duplicate of [How to access a local variable from a different function using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/), which is even tagged with C++ (as well as C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
   char userInput[MAX];
```

Is on the stack - so goes out of scope when the function returns.

Either, pass it in as a parameter or use `malloc` to bung it on the heap.

BTW: `new` is C++ - If using C++ tag the question as so and use `std::string`

Also `printf(userInput);` is invariably wrong

Comment: I think "ends it's lifetime" is better phrasing that "goes out of scope" because scope is static.

Answer (score 0):

When you use memory **dynamically** then it belong to the entire program rather than the scope where it has been defined.

In the OP's code the memory is free once control goes out of the scope of the function in which memory is being allocated "statically" i.e. scope of function *GetUserInput*.

Since this question has been tagged with label **C** despite `new` being used in it, I would be presenting your **C** version:

```
  char * GetUserInput()
  {
       char *userInput = malloc(MAX);
       //YOUR FUNCTIONALITY..........

       return userInput;
  }
```