# Pointer and printf()

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have the followin code of C :

```
float *dv(int a, int b);

int main() {
  int x ,y;

  scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
  float *pt;
  pt = dv(x,y);

  printf("The div is %f", pt);      
  return 0;
}

float *dv(int a, int b){
  float d;
  d = (float) a / b;
  return &d;
}
```

and I have some questions about it! If I skip the pointer declaration/initialization

```
pt = dv(x,y);
```

and I write into 
    printf("The div is %f", *dv(x,y));

it plays normally! But WHY? Where is my mistake??

Comment: your mistake is *returning a pointer*. As you just need to return a float value then just do that.

Comment: your mistake is returning a pointer to a local variable whose life logically ended the moment you returned to the caller function. printf most probably overwrites the dv's local variables before printing the parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `float d` defines a local variable with automatic storage, so the lifetime ends with the return of the function.

You need a variable which stays alive throughout the usage, try changing the variable definition to make it static storage (which has a lifetime throughout the program), like

```
static float d;
```

Then, the returned pointer will be valid in the caller also.

That said, you have a type mismatch

```
 printf("The div is %f", pt);
```

should be

```
 printf("The div is %f", *pt);
```

as you're trying to print a `float`, not a `float *`.

Comment: Nop, neither this is playing normally! I type 5 and 6 as integers and I get 0.0000000 as output.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior in both the cases.

```
pt = dv(x,y);
```

or

```
printf("The div is %f", *dv(x,y));
```

As you are returning address of local variable which will be vanished when control reaches end of function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it complicated when it can be simple:

```
float dv(int a, int b);

int main() {
  int x ,y;

  scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
  float pt;
  pt = dv(x,y);

  printf("The div is %f", pt);      
  return 0;
}

float dv(int a, int b){
  float d;
  d = (float) a / b;
  return d;
}
```

You don't need pointers here at all.

Also read this: [How to access a local variable from a different function using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/how-to-access-a-local-variable-from-a-different-function-using-pointers)