# How can I open a file in c using fgets() and an input file?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am trying to open the file indicated by the input file[100]. I keep getting a segmentation fault. I know that there is some problem with the fgets() function, but I am not exactly sure what it is. I can't get any code inside the loop to run. The final code is supposed to take the file from the first line of a text file, but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated, and I can post the main function code if needed!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <numInt.h>
    #include <string.h>


    char *getCoeff(char file[100], char chemName[50])
    {
            FILE* fptr = fopen(file, "r");
            char data[80];
            char *dataptr = data;
            char line[80];
            int count = 0;
            int i = 0;
            printf("%s",file);

            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr) != NULL)
            {
                     printf("Inside loop\n");
                     printf("%s",line);
                     strcpy(data,line);

             }
             fclose(fptr);

             return dataptr;
    }
```

Comment: check the return value of `fopen` if it is `NULL`.

Comment: The validity of the value in  `dataptr;` (`data[80]`) ends  with `return dataptr;`.  Calling code should not use it.  What is the point of unused `chemName[50]`?

Comment: See [Return pointer to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/how-to-access-a-local-variable-from-a-different-function-using-pointers).

Comment: Just after the `fopen` line add: `if (fptr == NULL) {printf("file %s is not a valid file\n", file); return NULL;}`