# Array returning issues with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I know that I can return an array with pointers. But when try to make this in two functions like that;

```
    int* decToBin(int num){
    int binAr[100], i = 0;
    while(num != 0){
        binAr[i] = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
        i++;
    }
    binAr[i+1] = '\0';

    return binAr;
}

int modExp(int b, int e, int m){
    int* expoBin = decToBin(e);
    int i = 0;
    while(expoBin[i] != '\0'){
        printf("%d", expoBin[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return expoBin;

}
```

I cant get any output. I know that I'm missing a silly point but I can't figure out.

Comment: There must be a duplicate Q for returning a pointer to a local variable...

Comment: Perhaps [How to access a local variable from a different function using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/how-to-access-a-local-variable-from-a-different-function-using-pointers)

Comment: where? At the expoBin part?

Comment: `int binAr[100]` dies immediately after `return binAr;` it no longer exists although an unreliable ghost might linger for a while.

Comment: So should I open memory with malloc function?

Comment: Yes, use `malloc` and `free` the memory later.

Comment: It didnt fix '''  int  *binAr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100); ''' I used like that but the outpu is still the same

Comment: Well, if `expoBin[0]` is `0` then you won't "get any output". And if `num` is *even* then it will be `0`.

Comment: Please update your code and provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, provide a `main` and show the inputs the functions are being called with.

Comment: Did you intend `binAr[i] = num % 2 + '0';` and a `char` array, followed by `printf("%c", expoBin[i])` ?

Comment: well its worked but when i enter '2' the output is 0. But it should be 10