# text to Morse code translator works but prints (null)

Tags: c, text, null, morse-code

I figured out how I can translate a userinput into Morse code. It works. The only thing messing with me is that no matter what input I give, at the end of the outcome it says (null) and I do not know what I have to change in my code to get rid of it. I thought it might be the end of the array wHich can not be translated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* tableSetup();
char* all_Cap(char sentence[]);
char* trans_to_morse(char* morse[], int b);

int main()
{
    char* morse[1024];
    char sentence[256];


    fgets(sentence,256,stdin);
    all_Cap(sentence);

    int b=strlen(sentence);
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
            morse[i]=tableSetup(sentence[i]);
    }

    trans_to_morse(morse, b);

    return (0);
}

char* tableSetup(int i){
    char* table[256]={0};

    table['0']="-----";
    table['1']=".----";
    table['2']="..---";
    table['3']="...--";
    table['4']="....-";
    table['5']=".....";
    table['6']="-....";
    table['7']="--...";
    table['8']="---..";
    table['9']="----.";
    table['A']=".-";
    table['B']="-...";
    table['C']="-.-.";
    table['D']="-..";
    table['E']=".";
    table['F']="..-.";
    table['G']="--.";
    table['H']="....";
    table['I']="..";
    table['J']=".---";
    table['K']="-.-";
    table['L']=".-..";
    table['M']="--";
    table['N']="-.";
    table['O']="---";
    table['P']=".--.";
    table['Q']="--.-";
    table['R']=".-.";
    table['S']="...";
    table['T']="-";
    table['U']="..-";
    table['V']="...-";
    table['W']=".--";
    table['X']="-..-";
    table['Y']="-.--";
    table['Z']="--..";
    table['.']=".-.-.-";
    table[',']="--..--";
    table[':']="---...";
    table[';']="-.-.-.";
    table['?']="..--..";
    table['!']="-.-.--";
    table['-']="-....-";
    table['_']="..--.-";
    table['(']="-.--.";
    table[')']="-.--.-";
    table['"']=".-..-.";
    table['=']="-...-";
    table['+']=".-.-.";
    table['/']="-..-.";
    table['@']=".--.-.";
    table[' ']=".......";


    return(table[i]);
}

char* all_Cap(char sentence[]){
    int b=strlen(sentence);
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        if(sentence[i]>=97 && sentence[i]<=122) sentence[i] -=32;
    }
    return(sentence);
}

char* trans_to_morse(char* morse[], int b){
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        printf("%s ",morse[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Outcome:

```
How are you?
.... --- .-- ....... .- .-. . ....... -.-- --- ..- ..--.. (null)
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.915 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer". Suggest you do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and check out the value of the last character and step thru the code as it processes that last character.

Comment: You could check if `morse[i]` is non-null before printing it: `if (morse[i]) printf("%s ", morse[i]);`.

Comment: Curious,  Nice use of `'A'` in `table['A']=".-";`, but then code reverts to `97` in `if(sentence[i]>=97 && sentence[i]<=122) sentence[i] -=32;`.   Perhaps`if(sentence[i]>='a' && sentence[i]<='z') sentence[i] -= 'a' - 'A';` or better yet `tolower()`.

Comment: Why are you re-populating the table every single time the `tableSetup` function is run? That's extremely inefficient. Just create your table as a global `const char *table[] = ...`

Comment: Aside: Bug: `tableSetup(sentence[i])` is a problem when `sentence[i] < 0`.  Suggest `char* tableSetup(int i)` --> `char* tableSetup(unsigned char i)` to avoid negative indexes.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli my teacher tells me to avoid anything global to learn how to hand over variables to other functions

Comment: Your teacher is right in the general case, but this is a really clear and standard exception to that silly rule. Global variables are not evil if they are used correctly and when needed. What would be nonsense is to have `n` global for example, but for a table that is being used over and over that's just the obvious way to go (and it's also *a lot* faster).

Comment: @WladislawKusnezow that array never change, if you do not want to have it global declare it `static`into *tableSetup*, also it does not contain `char*`but `const char*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a local variable from a different function using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/how-to-access-a-local-variable-from-a-different-function-using-pointers)

Comment: using `char* table[256]` you suppose the code of a character is from 0  up to 255, out of the fact a character can be signed as signaled by @chux-ReinstateMonica you cannot suppose that even managing `unsigned char`, use `UCHAR_MAX+1` or `SCHAR_MAX-SCHAR_MIN+1`

Comment: `if(sentence[i]>=97 && sentence[i]<=122) sentence[i] -=32;`?  Did you mean `sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i];`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle so basically yes, i am new to coding and my way `if(sentence[i]>=97 && sentence[i]<=122) sentence[i] -=32;` was the easiest way i had in mind. Thank for your advise, gonna use this instead of mine :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include an initialization line that says

```
table[`\n`] = "";
```

The problem is that `fgets(3)` includes the final `\n` character, so you try to print it, and the table entry you have for the `\n` character is `NULL` as you assigned it in the declaration.

Another solution is to map `table['\n'] = "\n";` so a newline is mapped into a string with just a `\n`, and you'll separate the output morse code into lines, as you do with the input.