# How can I return String to the main function?

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, cs50, c-strings

The goal is actually substituting characters in a string of plaintext to ciphertext. User input the key using the command line argument with the key input of 26 letters.

I encountered problem when I run the program, it got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. During the debug the code stops working at the function line. My question is what is happening and how to solve this so that I can create a string of keys?

Here is my code lines:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Declare crypting function
string encrypt(string text, string key_upper, string key_lower);
string valid_key_upper(string key);
string valid_key_lower(string key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Must contain an argument
    if (argc > 2 || argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution KEY\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // take the input from the commandline and validate them.
    string key_before = argv[1];
    int key_length = strlen(key_before);

    // evaluate the key length
    if (key_length != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }


    // Create initial key container
    char key[26];
    int evaluated_key = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++)
    {
        // Validate so that only letters
        if (key_before[i] < 65|| key_before[i] > 122 || (key_before[i] > 90 && key_before[i] < 97))
        {
            printf("Must only contain letters!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // Compare the current evaluated key to the existing key in the memory
        else
        {
            for (int n = 1; n < evaluated_key; n++)
            {
                if (key_before[i] == key[n])
                {
                    printf("Must not contain duplicate!\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            // copy valid key to the key container
            key[i] = key_before[i];
            evaluated_key = evaluated_key + 1;
        }
    }

    // Make lower-case and upper-case function container
    string key_upper = valid_key_upper(key);
    string key_lower = valid_key_lower(key);

    // get user input of plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");

    // function for ciphering
    string ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext, key_upper, key_lower);

    // print out the ciphered text
    printf("Ciphertext = %s\n", ciphertext);

}

string valid_key_upper(string key)
{
    // Declare variable container
    string key_upper = NULL;

    // Take the key and evaluate each character
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) // evaluate for 26 characters
    {
        if (key[i] >= 65 && key[i] <= 90)
        {
            key_upper[i] = key[i];
        }
        else if (key[i] >= 97 && key[i] <= 122)
        {
            key_upper[i] = toupper(key[i]);
        }
    }
    key_upper[26] = '\0';
    return key_upper;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a local variable from a different function using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570366/how-to-access-a-local-variable-from-a-different-function-using-pointers)

Comment: `cs50` is obscuring the fact that `string` is nothing more than a `typedef char* string;`

Comment: To the CS50 creators/maintainers: please consider giving up the pseudo `string` type, it only causes confusion in all cases but the simplest ones.

Comment: Sie note: you should avoir magic number like `65`. Use `'A'` instead which shows clearly your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `key_upper` in `valid_key_upper`; no space is allocated for the string, and you initialize it to `NULL`, so that when when you assign values to `key_upper[i]`, you trash the stack. You must `malloc` `key_upper` before you can assign string elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using null pointers to access memory.

For example within the function `valid_key_upper` the pointer `key_upper` is set to null

```
string key_upper = NULL;
```

then in the following for loop you are trying to dereference the pointer

```
// Take the key and evaluate each character
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) // evaluate for 26 characters
{
    if (key[i] >= 65 && key[i] <= 90)
    {
        key_upper[i] = key[i];
        //...
```

that results in undefine behavior.

There is no need to create such a string. You can convert a current character to upper or to lower case when a string is encrypted.

In general your code can be simplified. For example instead of this if statement

```
if (argc > 2 || argc < 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./substitution KEY\n");
    return 1;
}
```

you could write

```
if (argc !=  2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./substitution KEY\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `65` and `122`. Instead use integer character constants. That makes the code more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for everybody's answer, so I used `malloc` in the `key_upper` variable and solved the problem. Allocated 27 bytes in the variable. Also, I have simplified the function.

```
string valid_key_upper(string key)
{
    // Declare variable container
    string key_upper = malloc(27);

    // Take the key and evaluate each character
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) // evaluate for 26 characters
    {
         key_upper[i] = toupper(key[I]);
    }
    return key_upper;
}
```